# Fetch data from MySql table every 10 mintues

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySql database and I want to refrech the data (fetch data) from my table every 10 mintues not every new insert .

this is my code in php :

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * from `people` order by `date` DESC LIMIT 10;");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)){
```

Thanks

Comment: Use ajax with 10 minutes interval. Not a MySQL problem

Comment: Use CRON (linux) or schedule a task (Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a Jquery Ajax request to load the page every 10min interval.

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var dataSting = "row=1";
    var promise = sendAjaxFunction('load_form.php',dataString);
        $("#Loading").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
        promise.success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            return false;
        });
}
function sendAjaxFunction(url,dataString){
    return $.ajax({
        url :url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"text",
        data:dataString,
        error:function(){
            alert ("An Error as Occured...");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

and your php page is saved separately in `load_form.php`

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * from `people` order by `date` DESC LIMIT 10;");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is cronjob.

This cronjob works every 10 minutes ;

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /home/user/public_html/folder/your_php_file.php
```

Or you can use ajax post with sleep(600000)